# explicitly defaulted function cannot be declared as constexpr because the implicit declaration is not constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm trying to compile a C++ library (with gcc 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) and got this type of error:

```
> In file included from
> /root/pitchfork/workspace/unanimity/include/pacbio/consensus/ModelConfig.h:49:0,
>                  from /root/pitchfork/workspace/unanimity/src/models/P6C4NoCovModel.cpp:42:
> /root/pitchfork/workspace/unanimity/include/pacbio/data/internal/BaseEncoding.h:119:31:
> error: explicitly defaulted function 'constexpr
> PacBio::Data::detail::NCBI2na&
> PacBio::Data::detail::NCBI2na::operator=(const
> PacBio::Data::detail::NCBI2na&)' cannot be declared as constexpr
> because the implicit declaration is not constexpr:
>      inline constexpr NCBI2na& operator=(const NCBI2na&) = default;
```

The part of the code that cause trouble is :

```
class NCBI2na
{
public:
    static inline constexpr NCBI2na FromASCII(const char base) { return NCBI2na{base}; }
    static inline constexpr NCBI2na FromRaw(const uint8_t raw) { return NCBI2na{raw}; }

public:
    ~NCBI2na() = default;

    inline constexpr NCBI2na(const NCBI2na&) = default;
    inline constexpr NCBI2na(NCBI2na&&) = default;

    inline constexpr NCBI2na& operator=(const NCBI2na&) = default;
    inline constexpr NCBI2na& operator=(NCBI2na&&) = default;    
};
```

The part of the code that seems to causes trouble is the "= default". This may alos be related

I looked around but could not find a solution to this problem so far.
Here are some similar questions that could help:

[constexpr defining static data member of literal type that is declared const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726390/constexpr-defining-static-data-member-of-literal-type-that-is-declared-const)
[constructor of derived class cannot be constexpr if base class contains array member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097076/constructor-of-derived-class-cannot-be-constexpr-if-base-class-contains-array-me)

Comment: It [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c32bbd2a1633014f) with GCC 7.2.0 as well as Clang 3.8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a GCC bug. Assuming you compile as C++14, then the rules as written are these:

[[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.constexpr#3)

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following
>   constraints:
>
> - it shall not be virtual
> - its return type shall be a literal type;
> - each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - its function-body shall be = delete, = default, or ...

All of the above are in fact satisfied in the code you've shown us. So your assignment operator definition is okay, and should be accepted as `constexpr`.

---

This code (once the error inducing static functions are commented out), is accepted by [GCC 5.4.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4HsjjoeiL6BOr7Uq). So you can definitely chalk it up to a compiler bug.

Comment: so you believe that compiling with GCC 5.4.0 should work ?

Comment: @ThomasCokelaer - The link in my addenum is to an online compiler that does just that.

Comment: brilliant. I had missed the link. And I can reproduce the error using the GCC 5.3.0.